# Converting in-place a Postgresql database from SQL_ASCII to UTF8

Tags: postgresql, unicode, internationalization

(Not a duplicate of [4079956](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079956/converting-a-postgresql-database-from-sql-ascii-containing-mixed-encoging-types))

I have an `SQL_ASCII` database, `LC_CTYPE`=`LC_COLLATION`=`"C"`, which contains mostly ASCII data as well as some non-ASCII characters from some codepage, say `LATIN1`.

I want to transcode, **in-place** (no `pg_dump`/`pg-restore`), all non-ASCII codepoints from the `LATIN1` codepage to UTF-8 then alter the database encoding to UTF-8, e.g.:

```
-- change encoding first, transcode data after
UPDATE pg_database SET encoding=pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8')
  WHERE datname='sqlasciidb';
UPDATE tbl SET str=convert_from(str::bytea, 'LATIN1')
  WHERE str::bytea<>convert_from(str::bytea, 'LATIN1')::bytea;
```

or

```
-- transcode data first, change encoding after
CREATE DOMAIN my_varlena AS bytea;
CREATE CAST (my_varlena AS text) WITHOUT FUNCTION;
UPDATE tbl SET str=convert(str::bytea, 'LATIN1','UTF8')::my_varlena::text
  WHERE str::bytea<>convert(str::bytea, 'LATIN1', 'UTF8');
DROP DOMAIN my_varlena CASCADE;
UPDATE pg_database SET encoding=pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8')
  WHERE datname='sqlasciidb';
```

What, if anything, is wrong with the above approach?

Some problems I can see:

- after `pg_database` is updated, all connections to the database should be closed and reopened for the backend to take into account the new encoding
- all indexes based on the altered columns should be rebuilt

Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got the main gist of it. I assume you've already tried this with a test database? I did give it a quick test when suggesting it to someone and it seemed to work ok for me, although this was far from a thorough test.

My gut feel is to transcode first and change encoding after, because while the database is still in SQL_ASCII, you aren't going to have to deal with errors from postgresql trying to interpret not-yet-transcoded or improperly-transcoded data, and can look at data with relative impunity. OTOH changing the encoding first guarantees that only subsequently-connecting backends will write data in UTF8...

Also have a check for things like function bodies, view definitions, constraint definitions etc. that may need transcoding too? (you'd hope not, but...)

Comment: Turns out casting via domains is not truly supported.  Awarding anyway. :)