# Character 0xe2809a of encoding UTF-8 has not equivalent in "LATIN9" after migration to UTF8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, psql

Recently we have migrated a database from from SQL_ASCII to UTF8 encoding. After running the application we starting getting error messages like

> Character 0xc296 of encoding UTF-8 has no equivalent in "WIN1252"

So we came across iconv and 
The conversion was done in the following steps

#### 1-dump the existing database as

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin/pg_dump.exe" --host localhost --port  5433 --username "myadmin" --format plain --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "C:\UTF8Dump.sql" mydb
```

#### 2-convert using using [b]iconv[/b]

```
 "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe"  -c  -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8 C:\UTF8Dump.sql>C:\ConvertedUTF8Dump.sql
```

#### 3 create a nerw UTF-encoded DB

#### 4 import the sql from the step #2

we got rid of the error, but

on some other system we are getting

> Character 0xe2809a of encoding UTF-8 has not equivalent in "LATIN9"
>   problem after migration to UTF8

So we tried the same above steps with different conversion
like this

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe"  -c  -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8  C:\UTF8Dump.sql>C:\ConvertedUTF8Dump.sql
```

But the error still comes as

> Character 0xe2809a of encoding UTF-8 has no equivalent in "LATIN9"
>   problem after migration to UTF8

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* the source DB was `SQL_ASCII`?

What encoding was the text within the database actually in? Is it possible you have a mix of several different encodings in there? That's not uncommon with DBs that didn't enforce any sane encoding rules.

`0xc296` in `utf-8` is [unicode U+96 START OF GUARDED AREA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm). This seems like a pretty nonsensical character to have come from a conversion from a windows-1252 source.

`0xe2809a` in utf-8 is [unicode U+201a SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm). It isn't valid in ISO-8859-15, so PostgreSQL is correctly producing an error here.

I'd say you probably have multiple mutually incompatibly encoded strings in your database, so no one conversion applies to the whole database. Welcome to the joy of migrating from a mismash of mixed encodings into a strict utf-8 environment.

Alternately, if you know for sure what encoding your DB was and know it was consistent, you could try `pg_dump` without the `--encoding`, `iconv` the DB, then edit the dump and add/alter the `SET client_encoding` statement to reflect the new encoding. If you didn't change the `SET client_encoding` in your dumps after `iconv`, that might well explain the problem as you'd be telling Pg to interpret data you'd converted into `utf-8` as if it were `latin-9` or whatever.

Comment: +1,hi #1]`Are you sure the source DB was SQL_ASCII?` - yes.  #2-its mixed (english,spanish not sure which all languages) but mixed. #3.`Welcome to the joy of migrating from a mismash` ;( .. #4 `you could try pg_dump without the --encoding...` yes i will try this.

Comment: @psqluser If it's a database with mixed encodings you can't just `iconv` the whole dump to utf-8. You need to convert field-by-field. The PostgreSQL `convert` and `convert_from` functions may be useful, along with the PL/PgSQL `exception` clause.

Comment: @psqluser for mixed encodings see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079956/converting-a-postgresql-database-from-sql-ascii-containing-mixed-encoging-types